# Getting gnu screen to run on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, command-line

Is there a way to get screen to run on El Capitan? This [link](https://gist.github.com/bigeasy/2327150) contains instructions that are 4 years ago.

Comment: I'm missing any research here. Please add your problems with the instructions or submit error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)
2. Run `brew install screen` in a Terminal window

There is no step 3.

Comment: Just note that `homebrew/dupes` is now deprecated, and all formulae are now migrated to `homebrew/core` or removed as per [their github page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes).